# 'Non-unique column' error when creating a third table using SELECT INTO and FULL JOIN

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm attempting to create a new table from two existing tables, using the following code:

```
SELECT * INTO CustAndOrders from SalesLT.Customer 
FULL JOIN 
SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader
ON Customer.CustomerID=SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID;
```

However, I'm getting the error:

```
Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'CustomerID' in table 'CustAndOrders' is specified more than once.
```

My intention is to create a third table with all the fields from each of the joined tables. Obviously 'CustomerID' appears twice, that's what I am joining on. And if I remove the INTO part and execute as a SELECT statement, it works as expected.

Comment: Do you actually want two columns named CustomerID? Why the `FULL JOIN`, do you have sales without matching customers?

Comment: No, I want a one column named CustomerID. I'm using a FULL JOIN because... yeah I you guys are right, I need a LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just in case it isn't clear what the problem is the result of the `SELECT` has two columns called `CustomerID`. One from each table. A table can't have two identically named columns so the attempt to create a table with that format fails.

The solution is don't use `*`.

List out the columns you want explicitly and remove duplicate columns that you don't need or use column aliases to disambiguate any dupes that you do actually need.

Usually for a full outer join what you actually want is

```
SELECT COALESCE(Customer.CustomerID,SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID) as  CustomerID
       /*, other columns*/  
INTO   CustAndOrders
FROM   SalesLT.Customer
       FULL JOIN SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader
              ON Customer.CustomerID = SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID;
```

but it seems dubious that you need a FULL OUTER JOIN here anyway. Probably you need a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Thanks. I got it working with your help. I still don't understand why there are two 'CustomerID' columns though. If I perform the SELECT without INTO, it is successful, and only a single 'CustomerID' column is returned.

Comment: +1 for **"A table can't have two identically named columns"**. You can add  "in contrast with a result set which **can have** two identical named columns".

Comment: @AVPlol - Check again. when you do `*` that means all columns from all tables. Both `Customer` and `SalesOrderHeader` have a column called `CustomerId` so there will be two columns in the resultset named that.